# How do I install aclocal?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, autotools

How can I install aclocal from the autotools bundle in Ubuntu 11.04?
I tried to find it to no avail:

```
sudo apt-get install aclocal  
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev   
apt-cache search aclocal  
dpkg -S aclocal
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

*This was answered by the original user*

You need to install `automake` since `m4` is a dependency:

```
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
```

Then install `aclocal` via `apt-get`

Comment: In Ubuntu 12.04 that is not enough. Try automake.

Answer (score 167):

I had to install `automake` instead of `aclocal` directly with 11.10.

Example:

```
sudo apt-get install autotools-dev
sudo apt-get install automake
```

Comment: None of them helped me :(

Comment: I did this for 12.04 LTS.  The weird thing is I'm pretty sure I was building, in this case, the linaro android images using the same makefiles on this platform.  I'm not sure why I need to reinstall aclocal now.